# Access the state from another component/class in navigationOptions

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a component for the Homescreen called `Root`

```
  export default class Root extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      temp: 0,
      weather: "Default"
    }
  }

render() {
    return(
        <Icon
          style={styles.settings}
          name="md-more"
          color="white"
          size={30}
          type="ionicon"
          underlayColor={weather[this.state.weather].BackgroundColor}
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Settings", {weather:this.state.weather})}
          /> // tried passing props down here, but don't know how
);
```

}

`Root` has a state with fields for temp and weather, and I want to access `weather` in another component that I have, called `Settings` (for the Settings page of this app)

```
class Settings extends Component {

static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: weather[this.state.weather].BackgroundColor // this part
    }
  };
```

I want to access the `weather` field in Settings in the `backgroundColor` part of `navigationOptions` (using react-navigation). I've heard of passing down props to do so in other posts, but can't seem to get it working here.

Also, the way `Root` is connected to `Settings` is through an Icon press (like a button), which I do with the following: `onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Settings")}`. So I don't think I can render Settings through Root, but is there a way to send props down here?

(Example, if `this.state.weather = "Rain"`, then `weather["Rain"].backgroundColor` would return `blue`.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
props.navigation.state.params.weather
```

Instead of :

```
this.state.weather
```

CODE:

```
static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: weather[props.navigation.state.params.weather].BackgroundColor // this part
    }
  };
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work? Error is "cant find variable props", and adding `this` in front doesn't seem to work either

Comment: I can say, its hard to debug without a verifiable example, so, if you can post a full code snippet (con codepen or something else) would be a great help.